# How to fix this error of uploading code to stm32f103c8t6 using stlinkV2?

Tags: stm32

Hello everyone here's a newbie, I have been using STM32 maple mini quite a while and now I am working on chips level. But when I came to use the new STM32CubeIDE 1.0.1 it's been a big problem uploading code using STLinkV2. Using IDE is showing an error but when I'm using ST utility it's getting connected and can do changes as I can. Below I have added some pics in related to setting an error log and utility.

> Error message from debugger back end:
>   localhost:3333: The system tried to join a drive to a directory on a joined drive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... What pictures?

Comment: Which are attached above.!